# Get http post request body in perl

Tags: json, perl

Request header (from Firebug):

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Request json:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

So how to get request body in perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What webserver?

Usually POST data is available by simply reading from STDIN.

If you are using the venerable CGI module (under mod_perl or not), you can get the body via:

```
$cgi->param('POSTDATA')
```

(if, as in this case, the content type isn't application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data)

Comment: $cgi->param('POSTDATA') did it, I've tried it but I was typing postdata in small caps. Thank you :)